# Change date based on select value/month/year

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I want to change date based on selected value

```js
$(document).on('change', '.payment_options', function () {
    var value = $('#value_select').val();
    var data = $('#per_month_year').val();
    var d = new Date();
    d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + value);
    var subs_till = d.toDateString();
    if (data == 'month') {
        expire_date = subs_till;
    } else {
      //if data == year, change the membership valid till the value enter: like 2 years, 3 years etc
    }
    $('#membership_till_date').html(expire_date);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Choose Value</label>
<select name="" class="form-control payment_options" id="value_select">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
</select>

<label>Choose month/year</label>
<select name="" class="form-control payment_options" id="per_month_year">
    <option value="month">Month(s)</option>
    <option value="year">Year(s)</option>
</select>

<br>
<small>Membership valid from 'Today' to <span id="membership_till_date">"this have to change after choosing value/month-year"</span></small>
```

But the problem is it gives `+5 year` in the result, I want to display exactly the data like, if they choose value-data then display "till +5 month form now", "2 years form now", etc in the membership valid sections

Comment: "It will be very helpful if you can debug the code for years also" - Will also be helpful if you can debug your own code. Please see https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Comment: Thanks, actually I write the code, but it's not working. I am not good in English so I display it like this. Anyway thanks

Comment: I removed the downvote.

Comment: One issue is `d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + value)`. *value* is a string, whereas *getMonth* returns a number so if the current month is July and *value* is 1 you'll get `6 + "1"` which is `"61"`, so you're adding about 5 years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get the value of a text field, you always get a String back.

If, for example, you choose the number 2 in the value_select field your code will return a String value of "2".

```
var value = $('#value_select').val();
```

So you need to convert the String value to an integer, which you can do like this:

```
var value = parseInt($('#value_select').val());
```

Your code then works

Comment: Though `+$('#value_select').val()` is less to type. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, and @RobG thanks for short-cut xD.. I added my code for working when years is select like `d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear() + value); var subs_year = d.toDateString();` but in the answer it gives 13 months for a year, not 12. any idea

Comment: I got it, have to change some others line